# How to disable an observer through a configuration setting (rather than spec_helper)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, observer-pattern, observers

I've created an observer that observers all models for changes to the database.  This auditor observer works great in and of itself, but it destroys the testing suite. I'm unclear as to why the observer causes all my tests to fail. If you know, please tell me. (Incidentally, I'm running Rails 3.2.14.)

But more importantly, I'm looking for a way to get this observer to play nicely with the testing suite.  I was thinking of adding some sort of flag on the environment configuration layer that the observer class can evaluate at run time.  Then I would just set the flag to 'false' for the dev and test environments and true for production. But I have no idea how I would go about doing this.  Any suggestions?

I don't have the option of disabling the observer in my spec_helper because a substantial quantity of tests don't actually load the spec_helper.  Most of these tests don't actually make changes to the database, but hypothetically, they could and I don't want to have to dig through hundreds of tests files to refactor them.

So, I'm looking for a way to disable or incapacitate my observer for the entire test environment.  The configuration layer seems like the appropriate place to do this, but I'm not sure how to go about it.  I'd love to hear any advice on how to accomplish this.

Update: related post with more detailed account of the issues I'm having: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321693/how-to-disable-an-activerecord-observer-in-a-rails-engine?noredirect=1#comment26888767_18321693

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say:

- either you declare the observer in all config files but the test one
- or you load it conditionally: `config.active_record.observers = your_list if Rails.env.test?`

Btw, it seems weird you do not need to spec it too. Anyway, I know you can't sum up your app logic there, just curious.

Comment: I'm not so sure that either of these strategies will work, since the observer class will automatically get loaded when the app is initialized.

Comment: Did you actually  try?

Comment: what the doc states: `For an observer to be active, it must be registered first. This can be done by adding the following line into the application.rb`

Comment: Yes, I tried not registering the observer.  I added a print statement inside the class and watched as it appeared when the test app initialized.

Comment: Yep.  Even when I strip the observer file down to just a class that inherits from ActiveRecord::Observer, i.e. no callbacks whatsoever, tests fail.  The mere existence of the file throws the following exception "cant' convert nil into array."

Comment: UPDATE: The rails doc is not wrong.  Instead... I am an idiot.  I was overriding the ActiveRecord::Base in my tests.  I'm a bum.